# Is calling Process.Refresh() required for Process.HasFinished

Tags: c#, process

I am interested if calling Process.Refresh() is mandatory when waiting for the process to terminate by checking Process.HasFinished property?

I have a piece of code that works fine without the Process.Refresh() call, however I am curious weather this is a coincidence? I can see that a msdn example has the Process.Refresh() call...

If its not necessary, and Process.HasExited is the only property I need, are there any advantages to making the call to Process.Refresh() ? If not, is there a reason it is in the msdn example?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as you've noticed, MSDN doesn't exactly specify, what information is cached and thus needs to be refreshed using `Process.Refresh()`.

After a short (and probably incomplete) analysis of the class using reflector it seems though, that the `HasExited` property is "calculated" every time it's accessed. `Refresh` seems mostly to force an update of the internal `ProcessInfo` object, which contains information such as memory consumption, handle information etc.

On the other hand, `Refresh` doesn't really fetch all this information, it simply discards the internal cache. The information is only refetched when you access any of the properties. So `Refresh` has practically no performance overhead.
Therefore it might be more secure to call `Refresh` just in case Microsoft decides to change the `HasExited` implementation in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Does not directly answer your question, but if you want to wait until a process terminated you can use the `WaitForExit()` method of the `Process` class.

Comment: I know that, however since the called process runs for a long period of time, I want to use HasExited in order to keep my application from becoming unresponsive.