# Process.PrivateMemorySize64 Returns The Same Value Over Multiple Iterations

Tags: c#, memory, process

This code returns the same value in every iteration:

```
var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(process.PrivateMemorySize64 + Environment.NewLine);
}

// Output:
// 19853313
// 19853313
// 19853313
// 19853313
// ...
```

This code returns different values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    Console.WriteLine(process.PrivateMemorySize64 + Environment.NewLine);
}

// Output:
// 19865600
// 20336640
// 20791296
// 21245952
// ...
```

Does Process.GetCurrentProcess() take a snapshot of memory values?

MSDN's [GetCurrentProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page says this, but I'm not sure what the implications are:

`Gets a new Process component and associates it with the currently active process`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call the following line in order to refresh this:

```
 process.Refresh();
```

This should work for you now then:

```
var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(process.PrivateMemorySize64 + Environment.NewLine);
    process.Refresh();
}
```

Output I'm now getting:

> 26152960
>
> 26763264
>
> 27377664
>
> 27922432
>
> 28532736
>
> 29143040
>
> 29757440
>
> 30302208
>
> 30912512
>
> 31522816

From [Process.PrivateMemorySize64 Property - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.privatememorysize64(v=vs.110).aspx) in their supplied example.

In addition, from [Process.Refresh Method - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx), this is explained further:

> After Refresh is called, the first request for information about each
>   property causes the process component to obtain a new value from the
>   associated process.
>
> When a Process component is associated with a process resource, the
>   property values of the Process are immediately populated according to
>   the status of the associated process. If the information about the
>   associated process subsequently changes, those changes are not
>   reflected in the Process component's cached values. **The Process
>   component is a snapshot of the process resource at the time they are
>   associated. To view the current values for the associated process,
>   call the Refresh method.**

See [this StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756999/is-calling-process-refresh-required-for-process-hasfinished) for some additional information around what is a snapshot and what is not in terms of properties.